# How to dynamically add rows to datagrid in vb6

Tags: datagrid, vb6, recordset

```
Set rs = conn.Execute(Statement)  //rs has 6 fields
```

I want to add the current row of rs, to the DataGrid. How could I do that?

Sample:

```
DataGrid1.<someFunction (say AddRow)> = <some operations with rs.Fields (say, Str(rs.Fields(0)) & rs.Fields(1) & rs.Fields(2) & Str(rs.Fields(3)) & Str(rs.Fields(4)) & Str(rs.Fields(5))  >;
```

Comment: The topic says VB6 but I see the use of ";" (C# Of course we don't use `Set` in C#)? And I also see the tag for `VBA`. Could you please confirm which one are we looking at VB6/VBA or C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new row like this.

```
DataGrid1.Rows = DataGrid1.Rows + 1
```

And columns like this

```
DataGrid1.Cols = DataGrid1.Cols + 1
```

After that you can fill the grid like this.

```
DataGrid1.TextMatrix(<row>,<column>) = rs.Fields(0)
DataGrid1.TextMatrix(<row>,<column+1>) = rs.Fields(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is oldschool, but how about binding the entire recordset to the datagrid at once:

```
Set DataGrid1.DataSource = rs
DataGrid1.Refresh
```